# Function Notation question that needs an answer

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, notation

$f(x)= f(x+1)+3$ and $f(2)= 5$, determine the value of $f(8)$.

I don't understand how $f(x)$ can equal $f(x+1)+3$

Comment: If it helps to clarify the question, it is not *defining* $f$ by the rule $f(x)=f(x+1)+3$. It is saying that $f$ is a function which satisfies this equation for all $x$.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially re arrange the equation to: $f(x+1)=f(x)-3$

so $f(8)=f(7)-3=f(6)-3-3=.....=f(2)-18=5-18=-13$ using $f(2)=5$

so $f(8)=-13$

Answer (score 1):

It means that $f(x+1) = f(x) - 3$. Now you can find values of $f(x)$ consequently.

Answer (score 0):

This just means that if the point $(x,y)$ is on the graph of $f$, then so is the point $(x+1, y-3)$. So if you have a starting point, you can move to some specific other points on the graph by stepping $1$ unit to the right and $3$ units down. Then, since you are at a new point now, you can repeat this procedure: right $1$, down $3$; right $1$, down $3$; etc.

So, since you are told a starting point $(2,5)$, just step along until you reach a point with $x=8$. The sequence of points is $(\boxed{2},5),(\boxed{3},2),(\boxed{4},-1),(\boxed{5},-4),(\boxed{6},-7),(\boxed{7},-10),(\boxed{8},-13)$. So $f(8)=-13$.

(Remember, the points on the graph are pairs $\left( x,f(x)\right)$ for various values of $x$.)